# Is there a way to forcefully evalulate an inline Ruby expression within a Mustache template?

Tags: ruby, mustache

Just curious if this is possible.
Given some template:

```
<body>
 <title>{{title}}</title>
 <h1>{{description}}</h1>
</body>
```

How could you evaluate a Ruby expression in place of `{{description}}`?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence in [Mustache page](https://github.com/mustache/mustache):

> "It emphasizes separating logic from presentation: it is impossible to embed application logic in this template language."

If you want a more "dynamic" field, you need to define it on the object being rendered, not in the template.

Look for the `taxed_value` example a bit down the page to illustrate how to embed custom expressions:

```
class Simple < Mustache
  # ...
  def taxed_value
    value * 0.6
  end
  # ...
end
```